# PHP file permissions

Tags: php, permissions, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I just launched an ec2 server and put all the php code on the server and I need to change the permissions so that a user cant go to the site like `http:example.com/admin` and see the list of php files....Do I need to change the permissions on the entire folder or each file or is there a recursive `-R` command that will work ...I think they are all currently 777 ...which is bad

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to disable just the listing of files, and not access to the files themselves, then you'll want to disable the INDEXES option in Apache for that folder.  Something like this in the apache config would probably be best.

```
<Directory /www/somefolder>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your website is in an admin folder in the root of your webserver you can drop a .htaccess file in the admin root containing:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this PHP code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] == "insert_your_clientip_here") {
  echo "";
} else {
  return;
}
```

or use a password

```
<?php
$password="mypasswordhere";

if (isset($_GET[$password]);) {
  echo "";
} else {
  return;
}
```

then go to admin.php?mypasswordhere
(this isn't brute force proof so use a very strong password)